# Difference between inclusive and exclusive?

Tags: java

I feel like it's a simple concept, but I'm having trouble with inclusive and exclusive: particularly concerning random number generator.

For instance, if I wanted a value 2-8 (including 2 and 8), that would be inclusive, correct?

And how would that code look?
Something like this:
nextInt(8 - 2) + 2; ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For instance, if I wanted a value 2-8 (including 2 and 8), that would be inclusive, correct?

**Yes**. Inclusive includes; Exclusive excludes.

The range `2-8` inclusive is 7 unique values (2,3,4,5,6,7,8); and [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) **excludes** the *specified value*. So you want something like

```
Random rand = new Random();
int min = 2;
int max = 8;
// ...
int r = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

Answer (score 4):

Inclusive means it includes the number. Exclusive means it does not. The `Random.nextInt(limit)` is inclusive of 0, and exclusive of the limit. This approach allows using, e.g., the size of an array in a random number:

```
int[] arr = new int[6];  //size will be 6
Random rnd = new Random();
int i = arr[rnd.nextInt(arr.length));  //will return between [0] and [5]
```

For a value between 2 and 8, you know that the `.nextInt(limit)` will return between 0 and limit, so `.nextInt(7) + 2` will give a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 7 (exclusive, which is 6). Adding + 2 will be between 2 and 8 (inclusive of both), since it will be between (0 + 2) and (6 + 2).