# What does inclusive mean?

Tags: java

In java, what does inclusive mean? Say you want a whole number of scale 2 to 6 inclusive. What would that mean?

Comment: That's more of an English language question that a programming one!

Comment: 2<=x<=6 where x is the whole number.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378316/difference-between-inclusive-and-exclusive

Comment: Good link, @Arctigor; this question may be a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 3):

Inclusive means that you "include" the end values. There isn't really any such thing as "2 to 6 inclusive" because you aren't stating which end values are meant to actually be included. But im going to assume you want to include both end values as this is usually the case in programming.

If you want 2 to 6 including both 2 and 6 you write this down as:

```
[2,6] = {2,3,4,5,6}
```

If you want 2 to 6 excluding both 2 and 6 you write:

```
(2,6) = {3,4,5}
```

Note how 2 and 6 are not included in the second example.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped